# Is it possible to work similar way with GIMP for GIF data?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, gif

[image: GIMP shanpshot][image]

I would like to put different size of borders for GIF data. With the help of Photoshop works fine and it is faster, but with GIMP it looks tedious task. After some research, I found **FAnim** plugin for the GIMP to get the similar timeline for the GIMP.

Now, I am wondering how to put border using GIMP. Is there also plugin like **Unify** available for GIMP?

or simple to ask, may I add border for the GIF data using GIMP?

Comment: Why is your new layer on the bottom in GIMP, and not on the top like it is in the Photoshop example? Also it looks like the layer is filled black. Can't you make a transparent layer then stroke your selection?

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank you for your reply. As per tutorial, the new layer should be added after the last frame of the GIF. When Timeline is selected in PS, it sorts layers in descending order. When FAnim is selected in GIMP, the frames are sorted in ascending way.

Comment: Unfortunately it's pretty hard to make a full tutorial here, and that's not what GDSE is for.  If the tutorial you are following isn't working for you, perhaps reach out to the creator of the tutorial.  I downloaded the plugin, and managed to do it on a GIF,  but as I suspected, the layer with the border has to go to the top of the layer stack above the background layer, and you then can "toggle fixed visibility" inside the plugin. From there you can convert to a GIF and it works. [See before and after examples here](https://imgur.com/a/LQt5Dhy)